# How to get the real size of the image in image list

Tags: c#, winforms, image-size

I have a piece of code which shows the pictures in a specific size. I want to get the real size of the pictures and want to show those pictures in their real size.

Can anybody help me in this matter.
Here is the piece of code which I am using to get the pictures.

```
private void btnZoom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    imageList1.Images.Clear();

    string[] pics = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("TestFolder//");
    listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
    listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

    imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(64, 64);
    foreach (string pic in pics)
    {
        imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(pic));
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

        item.ImageIndex = j;

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

It's a Windows Form App.

Comment: You can not get the original image from image list.

Comment: So basically you want to display the images in the list view without scaling them up/down?

Comment: Yes i want to retain the original dimensions of the picture

Comment: Either store the **Full Path FileNames** or the **Images** themselves in a **List<>**.

Comment: @Idle_Mind i get the code but now it's showing me the error of out of range. do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Post the updated code and I'm sure we can help you out...

Comment: @Idle_Mind     
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            imageList1.Images.Clear();

            string[] pics = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("TestFolder//");
            listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
            listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

            imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(Width,Height);

Comment: You can not show Images in `ListView` in original size. Think about  `ListView` as a thumbnail viewer for your images. Then by choosing an item from the `ListView` show the image in a `PictureBox`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei So what should i use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach...store the Image and its Full Path FileName in the `Tag` property of your ListViewItem using a `Tuple<Image, String>`.

Something like:

```
    private void btnZoom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        imageList1.Images.Clear();

        string[] pics = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\mikes\Pictures\Facebook\Backyard Wildlife"); //"TestFolder//");
        listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
        listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

        imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(64, 64);
        for(int i = 0; i < pics.Length; i++)
        {
            Image img;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pics[i], FileMode.Open))
            {
                try
                {
                    img = Image.FromStream(fs);
                    imageList1.Images.Add(img);

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.ImageIndex = imageList1.Images.Count - 1;
                    item.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pics[i]);
                    item.Tag = new Tuple<Image, String>(img, pics[i]);
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }; 
            }


        }
    }

    private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
            Tuple<Image, String> data = (Tuple < Image, String >)item.Tag;
            label1.Text = data.Item2;
            pictureBox1.Image = data.Item1;
            Size sz = data.Item1.Size;
            label2.Text = sz.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much.It worked and it's solved my one of the main problem. Thank you :)

Comment: thank you very much.It worked and it's solved my one of the main problem. Thank you :)